# select closing tags of all opening tags in a multiple selection

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I need to delete all `span`-elements with `class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT"`, but not their content. So only the opening and closing tags.

So I select one `<span class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT">`, press `cmd+shift+L` `delete` to select and delete all instances. But next I need to delete the closing tags without deleting closing tags of other `span`-elements (those without a `REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT`-class)

Is there a way VSCode can match and select all closing tags of all opening tags a "multiple" selection?

Extensions like **Auto Close Tag** or **Highlight Matching Tag** don't seem helpful in this case.

Comment: I don't know of any such extension. What I often do when the source layout allows for it is use multiple cursors by marking the first occurrence and then repeatedly press CMD+D until all occurrences I want are marked and each one has a cursor, then use keyboard navigation such as END, HOME, OPTION+LEFT/RIGHT etc.

Comment: Unfortunately VS does not understand multiple capture groups in regex search. Otherwise you could have solved it with that. Unfortunately I don't know any other solution either

Comment: @TD540 Is there some reason you don't want to use a regex?

Comment: @manoi I don't understand what you mean by "VS does not understand multiple capture groups in regex search".  It does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what did it for me:

- select one `<span class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT">`
- `cmd+shift+L`
- press right arrow (so I have cursors at the start of all the spans I want)
- press space
- press `shift+control+cmd+right arrow` to Expand selection twice
- now only the right arrow once more (at this point all cursors are positioned at the start of the correct closing tags)
- delete the closing spans
- once again select one `<span class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT">`  (add extra space here)
- `cmd+shift+L`
- delete
- done

Now I only wonder if it'd be possible to automate this...

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward with a regex, if you don't have span elements within span elements.

Find: `<span.*class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT">([\s\S\n]*?)<\/span>`
Replace: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

The following always works (excepts if you have this span inside a span with the same class)

1. Select `<span class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT">`
2. menu: **Select** > **Select All Occurrences**
3. <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd>
4. command: **Emmet: Balance (outward)**
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
6. command: **Emmet: Balance (outward)**
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Or using (they should have fixed the indenting problem, issue is closed)

(This is not always working if there are tags inside the tag)

1. Select `<span class="REMOVE_THIS_ELEMENT">`
2. menu: **Select** > **Select All Occurrences**
3. <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd>
4. command: **Emmet: Remove Tag**